# Column and row labels to single image

Tags: graphics

I have an image that consists on several subimages stiched together. I would like to add row and column labels to the subimages. How would I do that?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx} %for including eps graphics

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{image.png} 
\end{center}
\caption{Some text } 
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Essentially, my image is similar to the one in the following picture and I would like to add the text that is in red. Potentially it would be nice to have the `text1` `text2` be rotated 90 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Are the subimages in your image of equal sizes?

Comment: @Troy Each subimage is MxN, but all subimages have the same size.

Comment: Would it be possible to split the picture into 4 pictures? This would make it easier.

Comment: @Georg I woudl like to avoid manually splitting the pictures myself, as I may have quite a decent amount of them. A solution on where Latex splits the PxQ subfigures "automatically" (by cropping or whatever) is something that I would be also happy with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there are better solutions, but with `TikZ` you can do it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx} %for including eps graphics
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
\path (A.south west) -- (A.north west) node[pos=.25, above, rotate=90] {Text 2} node[pos=.75, above, rotate=90] {Text 1};
\path (A.south west) -- (A.south east) node[pos=.25, below] {(a)} node[pos=.75, below] {(b)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Some text } 
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Easy to use and neat.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} %for including eps graphics

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}


 \begin{minipage}{2mm}
 \rotatebox{90}{\hspace{50mm}Text-1}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{2mm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{1.png} 
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{2mm}
\vspace*{-120mm}
\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{-25mm}Text-2}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Some text } 

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the question is to apply the captions/text to a *single* image, judging from the title and the MWE

Comment: Indeed, the question is about a single image.